# how to display 1 month of database to a listbox with a checkbox

Tags: c#

so i was able to display daily data into a listbox but what if i use a checkbox which function it will display 1 month of the data what should i do ?

```
private void monthCalendar1_DateChanged(object sender, DateRangeEventArgs e)
        {

            //label1.Text = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString();
            lstres.Items.Clear();
            con.Open();
            string date = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart.ToString();

            
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from reservation where Date = '" + date + "'", con);
            //sqlcommand cmd= to choose all the data from database where date is from Date

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            // datatable = to represents data table
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            //sqldataadapter = to link database connection
            da.Fill(dt);

            //DateTime dateAndTime = DateTime.Now;
            // Will give you smth like 25/05/2011
            //lstres.Text = dateAndTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            //foreach to transfer items in an array and display it
            {

                string dateonly = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Date"]).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
                string show = dateonly + " " + dr["TimeStart"].ToString() +
                            " " + "-" + " " + dr["TimeEnd"].ToString() + "  " + dr["RoomType"].ToString();
                lstres.Items.Add(show);

            }

            con.Close();
        }
```

this code is for daily but how to do for the monthly any idea ?

Comment: so by the sql command is that trying to select row in the reservation table and find the date and im trying to pull this month. for example today is 18 june  i want to display the month of june

Comment: okey so i did your code and when i cheked the box i didnt get anything in my listbox

Comment: okey i was able to but now i have to checked the checkbox then press on the month in the calender then it will display . how do i when i checked the check box it can immediately show that 1 month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the whole month, you need to calculate the first day of the month, and the first day of the next month, you can do it like this:

```
DateTime selectedDate = monthCalendar1.SelectionStart;
DateTime fromDate = date.AddDays(-date.Day + 1);
DateTime toDate = fromDate.AddMonths(1);
```

and then, you can plant them in the sql command, like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"Select * from reservation where Date >= '{fromDate:yyyy-MM-dd}' AND Date < '{toDate:yyyy-MM-dd}'", con);
```